# how to use ssh transport file in phpstorm

Tags: ssh, phpstorm

in my project , I only have ssh ,no ftp sftp and rsync, I write php script in phpstorm
but I have not found any plug about ssh in it. 
I want develop on windows, so anyone know is there anyway to transport file to linux,

thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try using the scp command.

scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory